# Change stock Clock app timer noise?

Tags: alarm, clock

In the stock clock app (4.2 stock Android), there's a timer function; the one where e.g. you type in 8 minutes and an alarm goes off in eight minutes. However, the noise it makes is absolutely unbearable. It's like a smoke alarm. There doesn't seem to be an option to select a different sound. I'd rather not use a different clock app; I like the stock one. I just want to change the horrible noise. Any tips?

Comment: You could check out third party timers to see if they offer that feature.

Comment: Great way to end a meditation... I feel like I just got shocked with a defibrillator.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem and the annoying sound can not be found in `/System/media/audio/`, but in `/system/app/DeskClock.apk/assets/sounds/Timer_Expire.ogg`. In any case, it seems difficult or impossible to change.

There is more info here: 
http://androidforums.com/nexus-4/668411-super-harsh-countdown-timer-sound-nexus-4-how-change.html

Answer (score 1):

There are just 2 ways to fix this:

- either to fix an .apk for this app (change a path in source of that app to point to different sound file and build it from source. Or maybe you will be able to patch your apk using something like [android-apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/))
- or to fix something else (not an app):

Mount `/system` as `rw` (either using `adb` or RootExplorer or other program). Go to folder `/System/media/audio/`. It usualy contains folders `alarms`, `notifications`, `ringtones` and `ui`. Then you can find and replace that annoying sound with another `.ogg` file for your taste.

Comment: Solution 2 (replacing Timer.ogg) didn't work for me. Maybe the audio files used are in the `.apk`.  I simply [downloaded](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.deskclock&hl=en) the google clock (it's the last version of the stock clock)